# How to modify migration column data type in Yii

Tags: php, yii, database-migration

so I've got a pipeline setup on Bitbucket, where the deployments occur. Last week we setup this migration:

```
    public function up()
    {
        $this->addColumn('asset', 'running_hours','DECIMAL(4,2)');
    }
```

However the users of the application ended up going over that resulting in errors,
so now we need to change to :

```
    public function up()
    {
        $this->addColumn('asset', 'running_hours','VARCHAR(8)');
    }
```

But running tests seems nothing has changed as the numbers are still limited, thinking that the db is stuck on the decimals. How does one modify the table using Yii and its migrations ? Using Yii 1x

Comment: I assume you cannot add the same column twice to the same table. Did you remove the one in error if not there must be a change type command

Comment: the alterColumn im thinking but is that simply placed under this line of code and they run or do i remove the addColumn , though I've not seen that happen in the other migrations

Comment: Well the previous migration will have run, so this needs to be a new migration

Comment: So run migration with the same name and everything but alter the up code ? Sorry I'm very new to Yii and its a passing by project

Comment: Tried: $this->alterColumn('asset', 'running_hours', 'VARHCAR(8)'); , no effect

Answer (score 1):

Got it.

Used:

```
public function up(){
$this->alterColumn('table_name', 'column_name', 'new_data_type');//timestamp new_data_type
}

public function down() {
$this->alterColumn('table_name','column_name', 'old_data_type' );//int is old_data_type
}
```